# How set unique variable to prefab after instantiate with loop unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I want to set variable to my child prefab class ( ArchiveRow.cs ) for each prefab witch instantiate with foreach loop.
I can instantiate child in their parent's transform and access to their class ( ArchiveRow.cs ) but all child in thier parent get same variable witch I don't want it !

```
    foreach (var item in channels)
    {
        GameObject thisParent = Instantiate(parent, transform) as GameObject;

        foreach (var item2 in collections)
        {
            Instantiate(child);
            child.transform.parent = thisParent.transform;

            ArchiveRow archiveRowComponent = child.GetComponentInChildren<ArchiveRow>();
            archiveRowComponent.archiveId = item2.collectionId;

        }
    }
```

my result with code of above is look like=>

```
    thisParent(1) ->
        child(1) ==> archiveId = 100
        child(2) ==> archiveId = 100
        ...

    thisParent(2)->
        child(1) ==> archiveId = 200
        child(2) ==> archiveId = 200
        ...

        ...
```

But I want set variable like =>

```
    thisParent(1) ->
        child(1) ==> archiveId = 100
        child(2) ==> archiveId = 150
        ...

    thisParent(2)->
        child(1) ==> archiveId = 200
        child(2) ==> archiveId = 250
        ...

        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is likely references.

So,

```
foreach (var item2 in collections)
{
    Instantiate(child);
    child.transform.parent = thisParent.transform;

    ArchiveRow archiveRowComponent = child.GetComponentInChildren<ArchiveRow>();
    var myid = item2.collectionId;
    archiveRowComponent.archiveId = myid;

}
```

should fix it.

Comment: then Id question the values you're reading in, the fact they stay the same as the first is slightly suspicious